# update 2 column based on values from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables and I want to write 2 updates.
tbl_stage with id, flag (null) and count(null) column.
tbl_source with id, count, updated column.

Before update

```
tbl_stage                 tbl_source
id    flag    count       id    count    updated
abc   NULL    NULL        abc   9.0      false
                          def   3.6      false
```

I want to update tbl_stage.count=tbl_source.count and tbl_stage.flag = true where tbl_stage.id=tbl_source.id.
And another, tbl_source.updated = true where tbl_stage.id=tbl_source.id.

After update should look like this.

```
tbl_stage                 tbl_source
id    flag    count       id    count    updated
abc   true    9.0         abc   9.0      true
                          def   3.6      false
```

Comment: Add sample table data, both before and after versions. Also tag the dbms you're using, some of them have a bit different syntax for those updates.

Comment: @jarlh done as suggested

Comment: Excellent! (Too bad I don't know Postgresql very well.)

Comment: @jarlh - SQL Server is fine. I can help myself with the syntax

Comment: Can there be duplicate id's in tbl_source? Can there be tbl_stage id's without corresponding  tbl_source rows?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, there can  be duplicates in tbl_source. No, all tbl_stage id's come from tbl_source.

Comment: If there's a duplicate id, which count and updated values to chose?

Comment: @jarlh - duplicate id will have the same count and updated value true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 UPDATE statements for sure as updating 2 tables in one statement is not available.

```
update tbl_stage
set [count]=tbl_source.count 
    ,flag = 1
FROM tbl_source WHERE tbl_stage.id=tbl_source.id

update tbl_source
set updated = 1
from tbl_source WHERE tbl_stage.id=tbl_source.id
and tbl_stage.count=tbl_source.count
```

Comment: Do ***not*** repeat the target table in the `FROM` list. That will create a cross join.  Only use `update tbl_stage from tbl_source where ....`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You mean update tbl_stage
set tbl_stage.count=tbl_source.count 
    ,tbl_stage.flag = 1 inner join tbl_source on tbl_stage.id=tbl_source.id  ?

Comment: @santosh - Can I not use inner join, just like your previous update query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single statement, changing both tables in one go:

```
with stage_update as (
  update stage
     set cnt = s.cnt, 
        flag = true
  from source s
  where stage.id = s.id
  returning s.id
)
update source
  set updated = true
where id in (select id from stage_update);
```

---

<sup>(I chose `cnt` for the column name because `count` is a reserved word, and should not be used as an identifier)</sup>

Comment: Is this a good idea for update on million rows every 10 mins?

Comment: @RedshiftGuy: You asked for it... I can't tell if it's a good idea.